# Break a long sentence over several rows when using multirow package and in multicomn command

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to span a long sentence over several rows when using multirow and multicol packages. I tried several methods. but, they did not satisfy my requirement. finally, I ended up with the following code and the result. It'd be a great help if someone could help on this.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}

\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Ref. No.}
&\multirow{4}{*}{Project}
&\multirow{4}{*}{Total estimated construction cost (Rs Mn)}
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Amount to be allocated (Rs Mn) in each year}\\ 
    \cline{4-6}
& & &2018&2019&2020

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The `multicol` package and its machinery are quite irrelevant for the query at hand. Separately: Please provide an example of a long sentence that will span several rows.

Comment: You could use the package `makecell` and use it like `\makecell{Total\\estimated\\construction\\cost (Rs Mn)}`. Another possibility could be using another column specifier in columns with long sentences like `p{5cm}` which results in a column of 5cm width in which the content gets line wrapped.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also you should not use only a single position specifier for `table`. Better would be something like `htbp`.

Comment: \begin{table}[h]
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
 
 \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{Ref. No.}
 &\multirow{4}{*}{Project}
 &\multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{Total\\estimated\\construction\\cost (Rs Mn)}}
 &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Amount to be allocated (Rs Mn) in each year}\\ \cline{4-6}
 & & &2018&2019&2020

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: make cell was a good solution thank you very much. thanx all for the help

Answer (score 1):

in lack of information about your table i can only suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

to be sure, you need to extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and to table add at least one row with table body.

*mwe* for above image is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{3cm}| *{3}{C{1.5cm}|} }

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Ref. No.}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{Project}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\centering Total estimated construction cost (Rs Mn)}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{C{\dimexpr4.5cm + 4\tabcolsep\relax}|}%
                    {Amount to be allocated (Rs Mn) in each year}   \\
    \cline{4-6}
    &   &   &   2018    &   2019    &   2020                        \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DAPadme, you are welcome. if you find that answer solve your problem (on the best way) than please accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following macro useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\minwidth}[3][c]% #1 = parbox optional, #2 = number of lines, #3 = text to fit
{\bgroup
  \count1=#2\relax
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#3}%
  \divide\dimen0 by \count1
  \dimen1=\baselineskip
  \multiply\dimen1 by \count1
  \loop\sbox0{\parbox[#1]{\dimen0}{\strut #3\strut}}%
  \ifdim\dimen1<\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
    \advance\dimen0 by 0.5em
  \repeat
  \box0
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\minwidth[c]{4}{\raggedright Total estimated construction cost (Rs Mn)}}
\fbox{\minwidth{3}{\centering Amount to be allocated (Rs Mn) in each year}}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]